# Best data type for manual sorting

Tags: java, sorting

In the frontend of an application I am developing the user is allowed to **MANUALLY** sort a list of object, my object is composed like this;

```
class Picture {
   private String location

   public void getLocation()
   {
      return location;
   }
}
```

Now I have tried sorting using an `integer` but the problem is when adding an item I want it added to the bottom of the list, which means I have to check the last `Picture` and +1 its sort field;

```
   class Picture {
       private int sort;
       private String location

       public void getSort()
       {
          return sort;
       }

       public void getSort(int sort)
       {
          this.sort = sort;
       }

       public void getLocation()
       {
          return location;
       }
    }
```

Is there a nicer way to solve this? (I have to store the variable in a SQL database)

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look to the Comparators http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: `ArrayList + Comparators + Collections.sort()` - `Game, set & match` for you.

Comment: The Comparable interface still requires a variable to be compared with each other. You need something to check how to sort the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use an auto-generated sequence ID, and sort by ID. Or add a Timestamp, and sort using this timestamp. Those two techniques would maintain insertion order without needing to get the largest integer before inserting a new picture.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable interface so that you can use collections framework API to sort the list.

Comment: The Comparable interface still requires a variable to be compared with each other. You need something to check how to sort the objects.

Comment: How do you intend to sort the objects? I mean, using API or manual sorting?

Comment: Aha, missed it. Use a long type and store current timestamp there as suggested by @JB Nizet.